# Why is the default process creation mechanism fork?

Tags: process, process-management, fork

The UNIX system call for process creation, fork(), creates a child process by copying the parent process.  My understanding is that this is almost always followed by a call to exec() to replace the child process' memory space (including text segment).  Copying the parent's memory space in fork() always seemed wasteful to me (although I realize the waste can be minimized by making the memory segments copy-on-write so only pointers are copied).  Anyway, does anyone know why this duplication approach is required for process creation?

Comment: Note that the `fork(2)` man page under Linux says: `Under  Linux,  fork()  is  implemented using copy-on-write pages, so the only penalty that it incurs is the time and memory required to duplicate the parent's page tables, and to create a unique task structure for the child.`  I imagine (but do not know for certain) that this is the case for other modern Unix flavors.

Comment: The original, PDP-11 Unix realy, truly did copy all the bytes of a forked process: but it only had 64Kb of executable, and at most 64Kb of data, so it wasn't a huge burden, even in 1975. I would guess that EVERY unix and unix-a-like since about 1990 has had copy-on-write text segments, so I'm not even sure why books and articles propagate "performance problem with fork" any more.

Comment: Nowadays, fork is implemented in a similar fashion to vfork (http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=vfork&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current&arch=i386&format=html). It's efficient, don't worry.

Comment: Also note that there are lots of usage where you do not exec after a fork (or at least, does not exec right away): think of pipes and web servers.

Comment: You may thing is would be slow. But as @cjm says look at the alternative Microsoft uses CreateProcess, they had to implement threads early (may be the only thing they lead on), because CreateProcess is slow. (They also needed threads because `select` was broken, but that is another story).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It's to simplify the interface.  The alternative to `fork` and `exec` would be something like Windows' [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.  Notice how many parameters `CreateProcess` has, and many of them are structs with even more parameters.  This is because *everything* you might want to control about the new process has to be passed to `CreateProcess`.  In fact, `CreateProcess` doesn't have enough parameters, so Microsoft had to add [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CreateProcessWithLogonW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

With the `fork/exec` model, you don't need all those parameters.  Instead, certain attributes of the process are preserved across `exec`.  This allows you to `fork`, then change whatever process attributes you want (using the same functions you'd use normally), and *then* `exec`.  In Linux, `fork` has no parameters, and `execve` has only 3: the program to run, the command line to give it, and its environment.  (There are other `exec` functions, but they're just wrappers around `execve` provided by the C library to simplify common use cases.)

If you want to start a process with a different current directory:  `fork`, `chdir`, `exec`.

If you want to redirect stdin/stdout: `fork`, close/open files, `exec`.

If you want to switch users: `fork`, `setuid`, `exec`.

All these things can be combined as needed.  If somebody comes up with a new kind of process attribute, you don't have to change `fork` and `exec`.

As larsks mentioned, most modern Unixes use copy-on-write, so `fork` doesn't involve significant overhead.

Comment: In fact, don't honest comparisons of fork vs CreateThread usually show that fork is competitive with CreateThread?

Comment: Excellent explanation.  "Those who don't understand UNIX are condemned to reinvent it, poorly." -- Henry Spencer

Comment: Thanks!  Do you have a reference, by any chance?

Comment: I believe windows uses a "fork" system call in the end... However this is so low level that it is probably not officially documented. Windows likes cOOLaPIfUnctions that abstract its internals (which is relatively useful to the bad guys evading antivirus and such).

Comment: @Aki, nope, CreateProcess() literally makes a new process and builds it up from scratch, no forking.

Comment: But must there not be some equivalent of CreateProcess() somewhere in Unix? Otherwise how does the very first process get created? Unlike a mythological creator god, the first process cannot fork() itself from nothingness. ;-)

Comment: @StevenMonday, yes, but it's in the kernel's initialization code and not externally accessible.  It doesn't need all those parameters because almost everything is hardcoded.  It can only create process ID 1, a.k.a. the init process.  After that, processes are created only by forking.

Comment: @StevenMonday, the first process is hand crafted by God ( the kernel )

Comment: POSIX has in fact added a complex fork-and-exec combined interface in posix_spawn:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_spawn.html   Most software still uses the older, simpler interfaces though.

Comment: I believe the "copy on write" feature is a good reason of the use of fork : by forking an existing process, you can start immediately the forked process if it's largely similar. Only the differing parts will be needed to be written to a different memory location, not the whole thing, if there are similitudes. (ex: a bash shell forking another to handle a pipe : most of everything is similar in both bash processes, so almost no need to copy anything to a new memory location for the 2nd process. Just duplicate memory pointers, no need to copy the program binary over. Hence it's VERY fast).

Comment: @StevenMonday The first process could not CreateProcess it self, any more than it could fork it self.  “In the beginning was Init, and Init was with the Kernel, and Init was the Kernel. It was with the Kernel in the beginning. Through It all things were forked; without It nothing was forked that has been forked. In It was life, and that life was the light of the whole operating system. The light shines in the darkness, and the darkness has not overcome it.”

Answer (score 9):

In adition to the cjm's answer, the Single Unix Specification defines a function named `vfork()`. That function works like fork, except that the forked process has undefined behavior if it does anything other than try calling an exec familly function, or calling `_exit()`.

Thus pretty much the only use with defined behavior is:

```
pid_t ret = vfork();
if(ret == 0)
{
    exec(...);
    _exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //in case exec failed for any reason.
}
```

So what does `vfork` do? It is is an inexpensive `fork`. In implemenations without copy-on-write, the resulting process will share memory space with the original process (hence the undefined behavior). In implementations with copy-on-write, `vfork` is permitted to be identical to `fork()`, since copy-on-write implementations are fast.

There is also the optional `posix_spawn` function (and a `posix_spawnp` function) which can directly create a new process. (It is also permissible to implement them with a library call using `fork` and `exec`, and an example implementation is provided.)