# Why do we need to fork to create new processes?

Tags: process, architecture, fork

In Unix whenever we want to create a new process, we fork the current process, creating a new child process which is exactly the same as the parent process; then we do an exec system call to  replace all the data from the parent process with that for the new process.

Why do we create a copy of the parent process in the first place and not create a new process directly?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31118/why-is-the-default-process-creation-mechanism-fork

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The short answer is, `fork` is in Unix because it was easy to fit into the existing system at the time, and because a [predecessor system at Berkeley](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/sds/9xx/940/901116A_940_TimesharingTechMan_Nov67.pdf) had used the concept of forks.

From [The Evolution of the Unix Time-sharing System](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/hist.html) (relevant text has been **highlighted**):

> Process control in its modern form was designed and implemented within a couple of days. It is astonishing how easily it fitted into the existing system; at the same time it is easy to see how **some of the slightly unusual features of the design are present precisely because they represented small, easily-coded changes to what existed**. A good example is the separation of the fork and exec functions. The most common model for the creation of new processes involves specifying a program for the process to execute; in Unix, a forked process continues to run the same program as its parent until it performs an explicit exec. The separation of the functions is certainly not unique to Unix, and **in fact it was present in the Berkeley time-sharing system, which was well-known to Thompson**. Still, it seems reasonable to suppose that **it exists in Unix mainly because of the ease with which fork could be implemented without changing much else**. The system already handled multiple (i.e. two) processes; there was a process table, and the processes were swapped between main memory and the disk. The initial implementation of fork required only
>
> 1)
>   Expansion of the process table
>
> 2)
>   Addition of a fork call that copied the current process to the disk swap area, using the already existing swap IO primitives, and made some adjustments to the process table.
>
> In fact, the PDP-7's fork call required precisely 27 lines of assembly code. Of course, other changes in the operating system and user programs were required, and some of them were rather interesting and unexpected. But **a combined fork-exec would have been considerably more complicated**, if only because exec as such did not exist; its function was already performed, using explicit IO, by the shell.

Since that paper, Unix has evolved. `fork` followed by `exec` is no longer the only way to run a program.

- [vfork](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/vfork.html) was created to be a more efficient fork for the case where the new process intends to do an exec right after the fork. After doing a vfork, the parent and child processes share the same data space, and the parent process is suspended until the child process either execs a program or exits.
- [posix_spawn](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/posix_spawn.html) creates a new process and executes a file in a single system call. It takes a bunch of parameters that let you selectively share the caller's open files and copy its signal disposition and other attributes to the new process.

Comment: Nice answer but I would add that vfork shouldn't be used used anymore. The performance difference is marginal now and its use can be dangerous. See this SO question stackoverflow.com/questions/4856255/…, this site http://ewontfix.com/7/, and "Advanced Unix Programming" page 299 about vfork

Comment: The machinations (data structure setup) required to use `posix_spawn()` to do the same post-fork replumbing jobs that can be done easily using `fork()` and inline code makes a compelling argument for `fork()` being much simpler to use.

Answer (score 47):

*[I'll repeat part of my answer from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123457/what-happens-when-we-type-a-simple-command-on-shell/123461#123461).]*

**Why not just have a command that creates a new process from scratch?**  Isn't it absurd and inefficient to copy one that is only going to be replaced right away?

In fact, that would probably not be as efficient for a few reasons:

1. The "copy" produced by `fork()` is a bit of an abstraction, since the kernel uses a **[copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_on_write) system**; all that really has to be created is a virtual memory map.  If the copy then immediately calls `exec()`, most of the data that would have been copied if it had been modified by the process's activity never actually has to be copied/created because the process doesn't do anything requiring its use.
2. Various significant aspects of the child process (e.g., its environment) do not have to be individually duplicated or set based on a complex analysis of the context, etc.  They're just assumed to be the same as that of the calling process, and this is the fairly intuitive system we are familiar with.

To explain #1 a little further, memory which is "copied" but never subsequently accessed is never really copied, at least in most cases.  An exception in this context *might* be if you forked a process, then had the parent process exit before the child replaced itself with `exec()`.  I say *might* because much of the parent could be cached if there is sufficient free memory, and I am not sure to what extent this would be exploited (which would depend on the OS implementation).

Of course, that doesn't on the surface make using a copy *more* efficient than using a blank slate -- except "the blank slate" is not literally nothing, and must involve allocation.  The system could have a generic blank/new process template that it copies the same way,<sup>1</sup> but that would then not really save anything vs. the copy-on-write fork.  So #1 just demonstrates that using a "new" empty process would not be more efficient.

Point #2 does explain why using the fork is likely more efficient. A child's environment is inherited from its parent, even if it is a completely different executable.  For example, if the parent process is a shell, and the child a web browser, `$HOME` is still the same for both of them, but since either could subsequently change it, these must be two separate copies.  The one in the child is produced by the original `fork()`.

<sup>1. A strategy that may not make much literal sense, but my point is that creating a process involves more than copying it's image into memory from disk.</sup>

Comment: While both points are true, neither supports why forking method was chosen instead of reating a new process from given executable.

Comment: BTW: `vfork` is essentially creating a new process without copying, which is why you must immediately run `exec`.

Comment: I think this does answer the question.  Fork is used because, in cases where creating a new process is the most efficient way to go, the cost of using fork instead is trivial (likely less than 1% of the process creation cost).  On the other hand, there are many places where fork is dramatically more efficient or far simpler of an API (such as handling file handles).  The decision Unix made was to only support one API, making the specification simpler.

Comment: @CortAmmon Why is `fork+execve` cheaper than `create`, where create is a function taking an executable? Both create a process, both load an executable from somewhere.

Comment: @SkyDan You're right, it's more an answer to *why not* rather than *why*, which Mark Plotnick answers more directly -- which I would interpret to mean not just that this was the easiest choice, but also that it was probably the *most efficient* choice (according to the Dennis Richie quote: "the PDP-7's fork call required precisely 27 lines of assembly...exec as such did not exist; its function was already performed").  So this "why not" is really a musing about two strategies wherein one superficially *appears* simpler and more efficient, when perhaps it isn't (witness the dubious fate of...

Comment: ...[vfork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vfork#Vfork)).  Your second comment ("Why is fork+execve cheaper than create, where create is a function taking an executable? Both create a process...") is sort of tautological in its assumption that creating something from scratch is really cheaper than replacing large parts of a copy, because the copy was initially expensive.  But what if the copy was actually dirt cheap?  That's part of the thesis of my answer.

Comment: Goldilocks is correct.  There are situations where forking and modifying is cheaper than creating a new one from scratch.  The most extreme example, of course, is any time you want a fork behavior itself.  `fork()` can it very quickly (as GL mentioned, on the order of 27 lines of assembly).  Looking in the other direction, if you want a "create a process from scratch," `fork()` costs only a tiny bit more than starting from a blank created process (27 lines of assembly + cost of closing file handles).  So `fork` handles both fork and create well, while `create` can only handle create well.

Comment: The original Unix implementations didn't have virtual memory or copy-on-write. So while this explains why `fork()` is cheap now, it doesn't motivate why the model was chosen in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar Plotnick's answer does that -- but note the question does *not* ask for the origin of the phenomenon, it asks *why* it is done that way **in the present tense**.  This is an answer to that (see my previous comment to SkyDan vis. it's about *why not*).

Comment: It's not clear that the question is about the present tense or history. But that may not be significant, since a big reason why we do it now is because we've always done it that way. Rather than change the API, we took advantage of hardware improvements to optimize the traditional method.

Comment: @Barmar I'll nitpick only because you seem to have levelled this as criticism, but *"Why do we need to fork..."* and *"Why do we create a copy..."* are unequivocally **in the present tense**, and the question *is clear* that way.  There is of course a historical justification (Plotnick's good answer), but there is also an ahistorical one.  WRT "Rather than change the API, we took advantage of hardware improvements" -> no one has referred to this, perhaps you should provide an answer of your own about that, because I'm lost as to the details!

Comment: I guess it depends on how you interpret "Why do we...". Consider something like "Why do we celebrate Christmas on December 25?".

Comment: Your answer referred to the hardware improvements: virtual memory, copy-on-write. Before these, `fork` actually copied all the process  memory, and it was very expensive.

Comment: A form of the question that would be unequivocally about the present tense would be _Why do we **still** create a copy..._.

Comment: The original UNIXes didn't use COW for `fork`s and copied everything, providing the rationale for `vfork`.

Answer (score 10):

I think the reason Unix had only the `fork` function to create new processes is a result of the [Unix philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy)

They build one function that does one thing well. It creates a child process.

What one does with the new process is then up to the programmer.
He can use one of the `exec*` functions and start a different program,
or he could not use exec and use the two instances of the same program, which can be useful.

So you get a bigger degree of freedom since you can use

1. fork without exec*
2. fork with exec* or
3. just exec* without fork

and in addition you only have to memorize the `fork` and the `exec*` function calls, which in the 1970s you had to do.

Comment: I understand how forks work, and how to use them. But why would I want to create a new process, when I can do the same thing but with less effort? For example, my teacher gave me an assignment where I had to create a process for each number passed to argv, to check if the number is a prime. But isn't that just a detour of ultimately doing the same thing? I could've just used an array and used a function for each number... So why do we create child processes, instead of doing all the processing in the main process?

Comment: I would venture to say that you understand how forks work, and how to use them, ***because*** you once had a teacher who gave you an assignment where you had to create a bunch of processes (with the number being specified at run-time), control them, co-ordinate them, and communicate among them. Of course nobody would do something trivial like that in real life. But, if you have a large problem that is easily decomposed into pieces that can be handled in parallel (e.g., edge detection in an image), forking lets you use multiple CPU cores simultaneously.

Comment: You can use threads to run code on multiple CPU cores, you don't need a whole process for that. The advantage of using a separate process lies more in gaining more protection. E.g. if you were doing something more complex than check if a number is prime, and it crashed, it wouldn't take down your entire parent process, you would just lose the one result. Also, you can reduce a process's privileges. E.g. if the parent runs as root, you can run the child process as the currently-logged-in user, so if there's an exploit in the child process code, it can't access other users' files.

Answer (score 7):

There are two philosophies of process creation: fork with inheritance, and create with arguments.  Unix uses fork, obviously.  (OSE, for example, and VMS use the create method.)  Unix has MANY inheritable characteristics, and more get added periodically.  Via inheritance, these new characteristics can be added WITHOUT CHANGING EXISTING PROGRAMS!  Using a create-with-arguments model, adding new characteristics would mean adding new arguments to the create call.  The Unix model is simpler.

It also affords the highly useful fork-without-exec model, where a process can split itself into multiple pieces.  This was vital back when there was no form of async I/O, and is useful when taking advantage of multiple CPU's in a system.  (Pre-threads.)  I've done this a lot over the years, even recently.  In essence it allows for container-izing multiple 'programs' into a single program, so there is absolutely no room for corruption or version mismatches, etc.

The fork/exec model also affords the ability for a specific child to inherit a radically weird environment, set up between the fork and the exec.  Things like inherited file descriptors, especially.  (An extension of stdio fd's.)  The create model doesn't offer the ability to inherit anything that wasn't envisioned by the creators of the create call.

Some systems also can support dynamic compilation of native code, where the process is in effect writing its own native-code program.  In other words, it wants a new program that it is writing itself on the fly, WITHOUT having to go through the source-code/compiler/linker cycle, and occupying disk space.  (I believe there is a Verilog language system that does this.)  The fork model supports this, the create model normally would not.

Comment: File descriptors are not “an extension of stdio”; stdio file pointers are a wrapper around file descriptors. File descriptors came first, and they are the fundamental Unix I/O handles. But, otherwise, this is a good point.

Answer (score 2):

The fork() function isn't only to copy the father process, it returns a value which refer that the process is the father or the son process, the image below explain how can you make use of fork() as a father and a son:

[image]

as shown when the process is the father fork() returns the son process ID `PID`  else it returns `0`

for example you can make use of it if you have a process ( web server ) that receive the requests and on each request it create a `son process` to process this request, here the father and its sons have different jobs.

SO, no run a copy of a process isn't the exact thing as fork().

Comment: While it is true, this does not answer the question. Why is forking necessary for process creation, if I want to run a different executable?

Comment: I agree with SkyDan – this does not answer the question. [posix_spawn](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/posix_spawn.html) is a somewhat fancier version of what might have been imagined 30 years ago (before Posix existed) as a **fork_execve** function; one that creates a new process, initializing its image from an executable, without even hinting at copying the image of the parent process (except for the argument list, the environment, and the process attributes (e.g., working directory)), ***and returns the PID of the new process to the caller (the parent process)***.

Comment: There are other ways to pass "parent" information to a child.  The return value technique just happens to be the most efficient way of doing it from a `fork` **if you assume you want `fork` in the first place**

Answer (score 0):

I/O redirection is most easily implemented after fork and before exec.  The child, being aware it's the child, can close file descriptors, open new ones, dup() or dup2() them to get them onto the right fd number, etc, all without affecting the parent.  After doing that, and perhaps any desired environment variable changes (also not affecting the parent), it can exec the new program in the tailored environment.

Comment: All you’re doing here is repeating the third paragraph of [Jim Cathey’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136637/23408#290292) with a tiny bit more detail.

Answer (score -2):

I think everyone here knows that how fork is work,but the question is that why we need to create exact duplicate of parent using fork?
**Answer**==>Take an example of server (without fork),while client-1 is accessing the server,if at the same time second client-2 is arrived and wants to access the server but server not give the permission to the newly arrived client-2 because server is busy to serve client-1 so client-2 has to wait.after all the services to the client-1 is finish,client-2 is now able to access the server.Now consider if at the same time client-3 arrive ,so client-3 has to wait till all the services to the client-2 is finish.Take the scenario where the thousands of clients need to access the server at the same time...then all the clients has to wait(server is busy!!).

This is avoided by creating(using fork)exact duplicate copy(i.e child) of server,where each child (which is exact duplicate copy of its parent i.e server) is dedicated to the newly arrived client,thus simultaneously all the clients access the same server.

Comment: This is why server *processes* should not be single-threaded, handling client requests *consecutively* when they can be handled *concurrently* — e.g., in separate processes.  But the multi-threaded server model can easily be implemented with a listener process that accepts requests from clients and creates a brand new process in which to run the client-service program. The only advantage that is offered by the ``fork`` call that copies the parent process is that you don’t have to have two separate programs — but having separate programs (e.g., ``inetd``) can make the system more modular.