# Why do some programs return to the shell immediately while others don't until execution is complete?

Tags: shell, process, background-process

I have read from the [Modern Operating systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136006639) book that when a command is run, the shell creates a child process, waits for it until the child has finished execution and then waits for another command from the user. This is indeed the case for many programs like `gedit`. The terminal doesn't take commands until I have closed `gedit`. However when I open [atom](https://atom.io/) code editor, the shell returns immediately, ready to accept the next command even with the editor running. Closing the terminal **does not** close atom. Does this mean that the editor opened not as a child process? What is the underlying mechanism that makes this possible?

Running `ps au | grep atom` gives

```
<username>      8042  0.0  0.0  15944  2264 pts/1    S+   00:55   0:00 grep --color=auto atom
```

Comment: After starting atom editor, can you run `ps au | grep atom` in terminal and add output to your question?

Comment: @kirill-a I have updated the question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The question asks about two types of programs:

1. programs which interact with the user in the shell, and
2. programs which do *not* interact with the user in the shell.

In the first case, programs which interact with the user in the shell are designed to run to completion before returning control to the shell.  Nothing special is done.

The second case is more complicated.  Typically the program will *fork* (making a copy of itself in memory), and arrange to remove its association with the shell's *controlling terminal*, and may *execute* another program — which runs independently of the original shell.  You may see messages from the second program, but it usually does not otherwise interact with you.  Depending on how it is used, you may have

- a *daemon* (server) process, or
- the program may run in a new window.  Graphical editors do the latter.

Further reading:

- [How do fork and exec work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179604/how-do-fork-and-exec-work)
- [Why do we need to fork to create new processes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136637/why-do-we-need-to-fork-to-create-new-processes/136673#136673)
- [What's the difference between running a program as a daemon and forking it into background with '&'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56495/whats-the-difference-between-running-a-program-as-a-daemon-and-forking-it-into)
- [fork() and exec() confusion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231766/fork-and-exec-confusion)

Comment: The part about forking and disassociating from the terminal is often done by calling the `daemon` library function which does all of this.

Comment: To avoid getting a controlling terminal, [double fork is used](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html#ss10.3)

Comment: To both comments: the function isn't in POSIX, and I'm aware of controlling terminals, but kept the answer short and simple.  I've used double-fork since the late 1980s.