# Why fork() copy all data the same as parent?

Tags: kernel

In my understanding, fork() will copy all data to its child, only different is PID.

It is strange to me when we want to run a new program, we want a new resource, ex: new free memory space, new execution code ....etc.

why do we need to copy a totally different process then start (exec) our new program?

Comment: ... or [Why do we need to fork to create new processes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136637/86440)