# How to trace on continuously running process?

Tags: grep, zsh, strace, ipc

So I wanted to know how files are opened by `zsh` like `.xinitrc`, `.xprofile`, `.zprofile`, and exactly in which order. So I have decided to `strace` on `zsh` process with the `grep` command to see how the `open` system call is called and eventually I can decide and order how these files are loaded.

My command:

```bash
strace zsh | grep open
```

but as soon as I ran this it kept showing me the output for `zsh` and `grep` is not working. when I end the process with `ctrl+d` also nothing happens.

So is there any way to get this `grep` output on this kind of process?

Comment: Related: [how to keep stty sane after piping `strace` to `vim`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/588518/108618) See my answer there. I think `-o` will help you.

Comment: Read the [documentation of `strace`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace). It has options to limit the output to selected calls, e.g. `strace -e trace=open` or ...`-e trace=file`

Comment: @Bodo so I have used this command `strace zsh -e trace=open` but it also outputs some other stuff and I can't see any `.zprofile`, `.zshrc` in output, so does it also manipulate execution flow of a process?

Comment: `strace -e trace=open -o output.txt zsh`

Comment: @Bodo I ran it, and it gives me this kind of lines
`
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=276345, si_uid=1002, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=276346, si_uid=1002, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
`

Comment: `xinitrc` has nothing to do with zsh, that's a config file for `xinit`, not `zsh`.

Comment: You can search or filter the outout file. If you don't see any `open` you might have to specify options to `zsh` because not all files will be used in all situations, e.g. only for login shells or interactive shells, or the shell might have used other calls to check if the file is present before it would call `open`. `-e trace=file` will trace all calls that contain a filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strace` sends its output to stderr by default.

Here, you could do:

```
strace -o >(grep --color open >&2) zsh
```

To run `zsh` while seeing all system calls that have `open` anywhere in the name or arguments or return value or:

```
strace -e /open zsh
```

(short for `strace -e trace=/open zsh`) or:

To see the system calls that have `open` in their name (such as open, openat, pidfd_open, mq_open, open_by_handle_at, perf_event_open list might not be accurate depending on what system and version thereof you're on).

Or:

```
strace -e open,openat zsh
```

For only those two system calls.

That output goes to the terminal along with the shell's prompt and command outputs. You may prefer to send it to a file that you can inspect later on or live in a separate terminal or `screen`/`tmux` pane:

```
strace -o >(grep --color open > strace.log) zsh
strace -e /open -o strace.log zsh
```

To also strace calls made in child processes (including by commands executed there and their children), you'd need the `-f` option.

So see what opens your `~/.xinitrc` (which has nothing to do with `zsh`) and when, you can use the `audit` system (may not be installed/enabled by default on your system).

Comment: thanks this works, but for some reason, it also corrupts my `tty` and does not end the `zsh` process is there any solution for that as well?

Comment: @Visrut, why would it end `zsh`? When should it end it? If you don't want the strace output to go to the tty, redirect it to a file.