# Three Questions on Child Shells: Lifespan and Creation

Tags: shell, process, fork

1. Is a child shell's life over shortly after it's created? I.e., do its assets get replaced by the process that is going to be run in it? Say we've run `grep -r "something"` in bash, so our shell(bash) creates a sub-process, which is not "grep" initially, it's just a fork of bash itself at first, but then since we ultimately want the "grep" to be run, the assets of the child shell will *"rapidly"* get replaced by the grep's process. (In a diagram: Shell ---> "Child Shell"(short life?) ---> Process)
2. Do all shell commands create child shells? E.g., does running a command as simple as "ls -l" also create a child process for a tiny bit of time? Because the same reason(as explained in 1) applies here again, "ls" is a program in itself, and when it's run, we don't want its process to replace our own shell's process.
3. If the answer to 2 is "Yes", does that mean running a shell script which contains many shell commands, will result in creation of "many" child shells and processes?

Comment: For (2), see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401020/70524

Comment: [Why is the default process creation mechanism fork?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31118/108618)

Comment: There seems to be an overriding impression that fork is a bad (slow) thing, but I've always had the impression that it is a fairly light weight process, simply copying and create a new process header, memory, file descriptors are all the same at that point?

Comment: @XTian there’s some historical baggage there; `fork` used to be expensive, and it keeps that reputation even though it’s been cheap for a long time (since copy-on-write became possible, at various times on various architectures and operating systems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s important to distinguish processes and what’s running inside them (and your question suggests you’re aware of this distinction). Whenever a given program, running in a process, wants to run another program, it has two options: it can ask the operating system to replace it in the current process with the new program ([the `exec` family of functions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html)), or it can ask the operating system to create a new process ([the `fork` function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) and then in that process ask the operating system to replace it in the new process with the new program.

1. When you run `grep` from a shell, the shell typically wants to regain control after, so it forks, runs `grep` in the fork, and waits for the forked process to finish. So yes, the shell in the fork is short-lived, but “creating” the “assets” of the shell in the fork didn’t cost much at all on most current operating systems (thanks to copy-on-write mechanisms).
2. The same applies for an `ls -l` from an interactive shell. However, in some circumstances the shell will replace itself instead of forking; see [Why bash does not spawn a subshell for simple commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401020/86440) for details.
3. Running a shell script will create one process for the shell running the script, and one process for each external command in the shell, and possibly sub-shells for certain shell constructs.

Creating processes is cheap, but `exec`ing less so; that’s part of the reason why people often care about limiting the number of processes being used. Two other reasons, which are perhaps more important, are that starting a program involves the cost of that’s program’s startup, and often involves repeating parts of an overall process (compare `find ... -exec grep` and `grep -r` on systems which have the latter, or multiple invocations of `grep`, `sed` etc. compared to a single `sed` or `awk`). Once you start hitting speed issues in shell scripts because you’re relying on external commands too much, that’s often a clue that it’s time to use a more capable programming environment which will allow more data processing without involving other programs.

Comment: Thanks this completely answers my question. Can you please also give an example for the last sentence in your answer(a more capable programming environment which...).

Comment: Perl, Python...